# why javascript number is called a primitive when it has __proto__

Tags: javascript

```
var num = 1;
typeof num;  //prints number
console.log(num.__proto__); //prints Number
console.log(num.__proto__.__proto__); //prints Object
```

When variable num is behaving like a typical Object then why number is called primitive in javascript?

Comment: To summarize the answer from these other questions: Primitives are automatically put into their appropriate wrappers (in this case, `Number`) when you use them like objects.